# Association cause foreing key mismatch error

Tags: sqlite, sequelize.js, associations

I am currently experimenting on sequelize.js and more specifically in associations. What i am trying to achieve is the following. I have to models:

1. user
2. position

My logic is the following:

1. A user can or cannot have a position assigned to it
2. If a user has a position, the id of the position is stored in field "assignedPositionId" of users table.
3. If a user does not have a position, then "assignedPositionId" value is set to null.
4. A position can be assigned to more than one users

The issue i am facing is, that i can successfully create a user, but i am unable to create a position! I always keep getting the error message:

```
SQLITE_ERROR: foreign key mismatch - "positions" referencing "users"
```

```
User.hasOne(Position, {
  sourceKey: "assignedPositionId",
  foreignKey: "id",
  as: "position"
});

Position.hasMany(User, {
  sourceKey: "id",
  foreignKey: "assignedPositionId",
  as: "users",

});
```

I know it's something more than easy - maybe it's late but i really can't figure out what goes wrong! Your help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@KenOn10, thank you for your providing a suggestion. After carefully reading documentation and performing several tests, i ended up with the following approach, which works perfectly:

```
User.hasMany(Position, {
  as: "position",
  sourceKey: "assignedPositionId",
  foreignKey: "id",
  constraints: false
});

Position.belongsTo(User, {
  as: "users",
  foreignKey: "assignedPositionId",
  constraints: false
});
```

Thank you again for your time.

Answer (score 1):

I've had problems using hasOne in these cases, tend to use belongsTo instead, e.g.

```
User.belongsTo(Position, {
   foreignKey: "assignedPositionId",
   as: "position"
});
```

That said, what does the SQL generated look like when you create a Position?  Can you execute this directly in the Sqlite shell?  That type of error message sometimes suggests a problem with your table PKs.

Comment: see how I solved it in my answer. And really appreciate your help - suggestion. constraints : false did the trick in my case.